# Windows Batch file to remove text after a delimiter

Tags: batch-file

I'm having trouble creating a batch file that takes a file `file.txt` and removes the text after a delimiter and creates a new file with the changes.

Ex:

`file.txt` would contain:

```
ashlasfj/asdkasdkj/asdkjasd
jhsdkfjhsdf/ajhsjduias/asjhfhsd
```

the `newfile.txt` would keep everything prior to the first `/`:

```
ashlasfj
jhsdkfjhsdf
```

I was thinking of using a for loop:

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=/" %%A in (test.txt) do (
    something here
)

Comment: What OS is this for? Since you're saying "batch" I assume it's Windows, but you need to make that clear.

Comment: Sorry the <br> wasn't supposed to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=1 delims=/" %%a in (test.txt) do (echo %%a >> newfile.txt)
```