# How do I ignore comments using importdata in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I had to update MATLAB recently from 2008 to 2014.

MATLAB's  `importdata`  no longer outputs just an array of useable values if there's any non-number text in the file. Testing shows that if I remove all my comments from my file,  `importdata`  returns the required data.

I tried something like this

```
structure = importdata('filename.txt')
structure.data
```

but my first line, which has a comment at the end of line (and thus non-number text)  gets cut off. I have a bunch of comments throughout my data files and I'd rather not have to remove all my comments.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902138/importing-text-files-with-comments-in-matlab) seems out of date.

Is `textscan` the only way to fix this?

Data file I've been working with.

```
% Vin: 5 MHz 6.5 mV pk-pk
% ADRF: Pre: 6 dB, Filt: 31 MHz, VGA: 28 dB, Post: 12 dB
% VGain Vin     Vout
0   6.51    4.55 % Dirty input
40  6.52    4.57
70  6.54    4.60
110 6.55    4.88
160 6.54    6.21
200 6.53    7.83
240 6.54    10.36
270 6.53    12.95
320 6.53    18.10
360 6.52    24.70
400 6.52    32.20
440 6.51    44.60
480 6.51    57.90
520 6.52    79.50
560 6.51    105.3
600 6.53    147.9
640 6.54    195
680 6.53    272
720 6.51    357
760 6.50    500
800 6.50    677
840 6.47    881
880 6.47    993
920 6.47    1012
960 6.47    1012
1000    6.47    1012
```

Comment: @Divakar I'd expect it to work similar to `importdata` of 2008. For this file it'd return a 25x3 double the first line of which would be `0    6.51    4.55`. However `structure.data(1,:)` currently returns `40.0000    6.5200    4.5700 `

Comment: Can you ever have more than one `%` in a line?

Comment: Possibly? I'd expect it to just ignore the rest of the line including the second `%`

Comment: if you insist on your dirty inputs, `textscan` is the easiest way to go. Or you do some [batch processing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888259/windows-batch-file-to-remove-text-after-a-delimiter) in advance.

Comment: yes `textscan` would be the way to go. It is still better than having to go with `fscanf`. Actually, `importdata` is just a wrapper but internally it uses 'textscan', 'fscanf', 'xlsread' and other known import functions.

Comment: Also, since `importdata` is not a built-in function, the code is easily accessible. You can just copy the file 'importdata.m' from your old Matlab 2008 and copy it in your new Matlab path (would be wise to change the name though). Then use this old version instead of the latest one.

Comment: Is there a place I could find older versions of MATLAB code? It's not on this computer anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason why you don't want to use textscan? This works for me in Matlab 2010 and 2013:

```
fid=fopen('testdata.dat');
data=textscan(fid,'%f %f %f','Headerlines',3,'Commentstyle','%');
fclose(fid);
data=cell2mat(data);
```

EDIT:
As long as you don't have a comment in the first line of your data, `importdata('testdata.dat')` should work fine. There seems to be a change in the way the number of headerlines is determined between the Matlab versions you are comparing. If you prefer importdata to textscan, try this:

```
data=importdata('testdata.dat',' ',3)
```

then `data.data` should contain all your data and it is still quite readable.

Comment: true, readability suffers a bit, but if it works you can always package that into your own function `data=MyImportDataFunction('testdata.dat');`. This function would include the first few lines of code given by Divakar. Readability would be restored ;)

Comment: Seems a bit unsafe in case there's something to note on the first data entry, but it's definitely the best solution so far.